# how change font of captcha numbers?

Tags: php, captcha

hi i have form that have captcha and i want number of captcha show arabic or persian but when i change font of code this is not work. how can i make that?

```
<?php
session_start();

$string = '';

for ($i = 1; $i < 8; $i++) {
// this numbers refer to numbers of the ascii table (lower case)
$string .= rand(0,6);
}

$_SESSION['random_code'] = $string;

$dir = 'style/font/';

$image = imagecreatetruecolor(170, 60);
$black = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
$color = imagecolorallocate($image, 200, 100, 90); // red
$white = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);

imagefilledrectangle($image,0,0,399,99,$white);
imagettftext ($image, 30, 0, 10, 40, $color, $dir."Yekan.ttf", 
$_SESSION['random_code']);

header("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($image);

?>
```

Comment: your question is not clear.

Comment: make sure you have font files on correct path

Comment: @b.desai font files in correct path and when i change font change face that

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](http://dk2.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php) about the problems locating the .ttf file? They mention using `putenv('GDFONTPATH=' . realpath('.'));` and then removing `.ttf` from the path. Others mention prefixing your path with `./`.